# What is the best iphone OS / SDK version to target right now?

Tags: iphone

Just starting out with my first commercial app for the iStore but dont have enough experience to know which OS to target.

My guess would be iPhone OS 3 but what are the implications now that version 4 is released?

also, should I develop for SDK 3.2 as being the most up to date version of OS 3 or target version 3 specifically?

any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no matter what your base iOS is you'll still need to compile against the iOS 4.0 SDK.

That said I still set my deployment target to iOS 3.0 simply my current apps don't make use of any of the iOS 4.0 features - there is no point in excluding a whole generation of devices because they don't run iOS 4.0.

I guess the argument really comes down to if your using iOS4 features in a way that is integral to your app. If you are then there is no choice but to compile (and deploy) to iOS 4.0 only. If not then iOS 3.0 seems to me to be best of both worlds.

Comment: Thanks James, currently I only have the iPhone simulator 4.0 in xcode to test my code on, any idea how i would get the 3.0 simulator added in?